# Sum function using slices with a numpy array Python

Tags: python, numpy, sum, slice, numpy-ndarray

Is there a way I could index through a numpy list just like how I would be able to within a normal list function. I want to go through 3 elements in the list moving up by one point every single time and summing all the slices. So it would go through `1,2,3` for the first sum and then it would go through `2,3,4` for the second sum etc. The code down below gives me a scalar error, is there a way I could perform the function below without using a for loop.

```
import numpy as np
n = 3 
arr = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8,9, 10, 11,12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21 ,22, 23, 24, 25])
start = np.arange(0, len(arr)-n, 1)
stop = np.arange(n-1, len(arr), 1)
sum_arr = np.sum(arr[start:stop])
```

Comment: `[n:m]` requires scalar values, not arrays.  That's just true when used in arrays as in lists.  Why didn't you use a list comprehension?

Comment: @hpaulj I dont want to use list comprehension with the for loop since it is slow. If possible I just want to use arrays.

Comment: For a start it's better to use something that's slow but works, rather trying some "I hope it works" guess!  But there are a number of alternatives for `moving-windows` - `as_strided`, `convolving`, `cumsum`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work:

```
sum_arr = arr[1:-1] + arr[2:] + arr[:-2]
```

This creates an array that's two values shorter than arr because the last element in arr doesn't have two extra elements to create a sum with.

If you wanted the array to be of the same length as the original arr, you could append two extra zeros to the arr array like so:

```
arr = np.append(arr, [0, 0])
sum_arr = arr[1:-1] + arr[2:] + arr[:-2]
```

Comment: Isnt there a better version where I can state the amount of arrays to sum the function with like instead of taking 3 numbers I would say 5 etc.

Comment: I have also updated it since I couldn't define the issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

To sum a sliding range of `n` elements you can use [`convolve1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.convolve1d.html) with all weights set to `1`. Use `'constant'` boundary mode with the default fill value of `0`. As the filter window is centered by default you need to adjust the length of the result at both ends.

```
import numpy as np 
from scipy.ndimage import convolve1d

arr = np.arange(1,26)

for n in range(2,6):
   k,r = divmod(n, 2)
   print(n, convolve1d(arr, np.ones(n), mode='constant')[k+r-1:-k])
```

Result:

```
2 [ 3  5  7  9 11 13 15 17 19 21 23 25 27 29 31 33 35 37 39 41 43 45 47 49]
3 [ 6  9 12 15 18 21 24 27 30 33 36 39 42 45 48 51 54 57 60 63 66 69 72]
4 [ 10 14 18 22 26 30 34 38 42 46 50 54 58 62 66 70 74 78 82 86 90 94]
5 [ 15  20  25  30  35  40  45  50  55  60  65  70  75  80  85  90  95 100 105 110 115]
```

Comment: Is there a way I could iterate the function without a for loop. As I have explained on the details above I am trying to make the function run as fast as possible.

Comment: this is why i proposed a solution **without a loop** (the loop in the example is just for demonstration of different window sizes, i.e. for any given `n`, e.g. `n=3` there will be no loop but just one call to `convolve1d`)